# Integrating Object Recognition into iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, image-recognition, object-recognition

We currently have a native iOS app written in obj-c. Just wondering if anyone has any advice/experience on integrating Object recognition functionality into the app. The basic description of what want to allow our user to do is to click on a button which fires up the camera, when they are in a room with objects (boxes, machines, vehicles etc) it highligts these objects (draws a box around them) which the user can then click on and add into the our system.

Any advice on how we could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Augmented Reallity SDK's which they have object recognition ability
i have used metaio SDK before and done this. but after shutting down the metaio i think the next good choice would be vuforia SDK. OR you can put labels which are defined as targets on the objects and put them on the objects and use image tracking.